# Restrict Retrofit/OkHttp to only Https

Tags: android, https, retrofit2, okhttp

I am developing an Android app which accesses different web services with retrofit. The base url is entered by the user in a field. Nevertheless, the client (retrofit or okhttp-client) should be limited to connecting to Https pages only.
Is there a better way than checking the user input to see if they use the Https scheme?

Comment: `HttpUrl` class has the method `isHttps()`. You could parse the url with `okhttp3.HttpUrl.parse(baseUrl).isHttps()`.